# sql - Return set with no duplicates from inner join?

Tags: mysql

Creating a mock help desk ticketing service.

I have a `ticket` table which holds all tickets created by the customer.
I have a `works_on` table which holds all tickets which managers have claimed and are working on.

In both tables I have a `customerid` to identify the owner of the ticket.

In the customer menu, they can check all of their tickets that they created, whether they are open, in the `ticket` table or being worked on in the `works_on` table.

My code below is giving me the same ticket from both tables. I only want to see the ticket once. How can I do that?

```
SELECT * FROM ticket
INNER JOIN works_on
ON ticket.custid = works_on.customerid
```

Comment: Can you show the definitions of both tables?

Comment: I think you're joining on the wrong field. You should join on `ticket_id`, not `customer_id`.

Comment: There shouldn't be a `customerid` column in `works_on`. That's a violation of normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

try using [Group By](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT * FROM ticket
       INNER JOIN works_on
       ON ticket.custid = works_on.customerid
       GROUP BY ticket.custid
```

you can also try using [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

> The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct
>   (different) values

Comment: This just returns one ticket per customer, not all their tickets.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ticket
INNER JOIN works_on
ON ticket.custid = works_on.customerid
GROUP BY ticket.custid
```

This will group the results where the customer ID are the same.

If not the modify the select into a SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: This just returns one ticket per customer.

Answer (score 0):

You're joining on the wrong columns. When you join on `customerid`, it finds all the tickets for a customer, and all the `works_on` rows for that customer, and creates a cross-product between them. You should be joining on the ticket ID, so you get each ticket with its corresponding `works_on` row.

```
SELECT *
FROM ticket AS t
INNER JOIN works_on AS w ON t.ticket_id = w.ticket_id
WHERE t.custid = :customer
```